# conditional statement expressing that current user didn't logout (is still in the same login session)?

Tags: php

Thank you in advance for your time.

I want to perform the following conditonal `if`:

```
if (current user didnt log out and is in the same login session )

{
Do_something;
}
```

How to express it using Codex functions? I want to add it to the following `if` but in vain.

```
if (
    is_single() 
    && !empty($current_user)
    && $post->post_author == $current_user->ID
  ) {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'process_postviews');
  }
```

Your usual help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Hello ' . wp_get_current_user()->display_name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback to my post. In fact, I already use the `if` statement you provided since my website is already a private community. The problem I have is that I am using a plugin that displays post number of views and it is incremented even if the same user refreshes the page. Could you please check the attached link?

Comment: Your code snippet & your question are trying two different things. Do you want to ensure that one user = one view, regardless how many times they refresh? Or do you want to *exclude* view counts by the author of the post?

Comment: I want to ensure one user = one view, during one login. 
Excluding view counts by the author is already performed thanks to S_HA_DUM answer in linked post. In that hack we used `remove_action`.

Comment: Then you'll need a bit more logic than simply removing the action. Can you link to the plugin you're using?

Comment: Thank you. http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-postviews/trunk/wp-postviews.php is the link to the plugin.

Comment: This really warrants a new question. I suggest something like "WP Postviews - Prevent multiple counts by same user", then briefly explain your situation in a little more detail & link to the plugin.

Comment: I agree with you, this is a good idea. Do you suggest that I just modify this post (edit it), or ask a new question?

Comment: I would suggest new; it avoids confusion & keeps the topic focused.

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this issue is in the link below, provided by TheDeadMedic. It uses the cookies principle and some array management.

[Prevent multiple counts by same user - WP PostViews plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104324/prevent-multiple-counts-by-same-user-wp-postviews-plugin/104331#104331)

Note that the there are linked posts to this post, that can be helpful to understand the whole situation.

Good luck.